SQL Group By Then Filter
I have two tables as follows:
Table A : contacts



Contact_Primary_Num
Displayed_Name




1
Smith, Joe


2
Doe, Donna


3
Jerry, Tom


4
Crocker, Betty



Table B : contact_notes



Contact_Note_Primary_Num
Contact_Num
Contact_Note_Date
Contact_Follow_Up_Date




1
2
2024-06-19
2024-06-24


2
1
2024-03-05
NULL


3
1
2024-02-29
NULL


4
4
NULL
NULL


5
3
2024-06-20
2024-06-26


6
3
2024-06-19
2024-06-27


7
3
2024-06-20
2024-06-27



How do I get a solution that groups by ContactPrimaryNum, filters by latest ConactNoteDate, then filters by latest ContactFollowUpDate for each ContactPrimaryNum?  Such as :



Contact_Primary_Num
Displayed_Name
ContactNotePrimaryNum
Contact_Num
Contact_Note_Date
Contact_Follow_Up_Date




4
Crocker, Betty
4
4
NULL
NULL


1
Smith, Joe
2
1
2024-03-05
NULL


2
Doe, Donna
1
2
2024-06-19
2024-06-24


3
Jerry, Tom
7
3
2024-06-20
2024-06-27



I've tried creating a Temp Table where I use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to combine the two tables and then filter using the ContactFollowUpDate from there, but it leaves out the "NULL" entries.  Example:
CREATE TABLE #ContactListA
     (
       ContactPrimaryNum int,
       DisplayedName nvarchar(max),
       ContactNotePrimaryNum int,
       ContactNum int,
       ContactNoteDate nvarchar(max),
       ContactFollowUpDate nvarchar(max)
     )
INSERT INTO #ContactListA
     (
       ContactPrimaryNum,
       DisplayedName,
       ContactNotePrimaryNum,
       ContactNum,
       ContactNoteDate,
       ContactFollowUpDate
     )
SELECT
     a.Contact_Primary_Num,
     a.Displayed_Name,
     b.Contact_Note_Primary_Num,
     b.Contact_Num,
     b.Contact_Note_Date,
     b.Contact_Follow_Up_Date
FROM contacts a
     LEFT OUTER JOIN contact_notes b ON b.Contact_Num = a.Contact_Primary_Num
WHERE 
     (b.Conact_Note_Date = (SELECT max(b1.Contact_Note_Date) FROM contact_notes b1 WHERE b1.Contact_Num = b.Contact_Num)
SELECT
     a.ContactPrimaryNum,
     a.DisplayedName,
     a.ContactNotePrimaryNum,
     a.ContactNum,
     a.ContactNoteDate,
     c.ContactFollowUpDate
FROM (
     SELECT ContactPrimaryNum, max(ContactFollowUpDate) as ContactFollowUpDate
     FROM #ContactListA
     GROUP BY ContactPrimaryNum
     ) c
     INNER JOIN #ContactListA a
     ON a.ContactPrimaryNum = c.ContactPrimaryNum AND a.ContactFollowUpDate = c.ContactFollowUpDate
ORDER BY ContactFollowUpDate ASC


ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Contact_Num ORDER BY Contact_Note_Date DESC, Contact_Follow_Up_Date DESC) see linked answer

@Charlieface Your suggested answer doesn't address the issue of NULL values.  Is there another suggested answer that deals with NULL values?

What do you mean? Nulls will be at the bottom, but in your case they are coming from left-joins so it seems there would be only one row per partition anyway, so it should just work. DId you try it?

Using a series of groupings and joins:
select c.*, n2.contact_note_primary_num, t1.dt, t1.dt1 from
  (select n1.contact_num, t.dt, max(n1.contact_follow_up_date) dt1 from 
    (select n.contact_num, max(n.contact_note_date) dt 
     from contact_notes n group by n.contact_num) t 
     join contact_notes n1 on n1.contact_num = t.contact_num 
       and t.dt = n1.contact_note_date
   group by n1.contact_num, t.dt) t1
right join contacts c on c.contact_primary_num = t1.contact_num
left join contact_notes n2 on n2.contact_note_date = t1.dt and (n2.contact_follow_up_date is null or n2.contact_follow_up_date = t1.dt1)

See fiddle
